# replace values with other values from another data frame with conditions, the others are unchanged

Tags: r, dataframe

my dummy data looks like:

df1:

rsID---------chr-----position

x--------------12------319

x--------------12------322

x--------------12------327

x--------------12------321

x--------------14-------412

x--------------15-------3123

x--------------17-------413

df2:

rsID---------chr-----position

rs12---------14-------412

rs20---------17-------413

My Expected result looks like:

rsID---------chr-----position

x--------------12------319

x--------------12------322

x--------------12------327

x--------------12------321

rs12---------14-------412

x-------------15-------3123

rs20---------17-------413

It means that I want to match rsIDs from df2 to that from df1 (in other words, replace 'x' from df1 with rsIDs from df2) only if corresponding values in two columns 'chr' and 'position' of df1 and df2 are the same. The other rsIDs do not change (still, 'x').

My attempt does not works:

```
df3 = ifelse(df1$chr == df2$chr & df1$position == df2$position, df1$rsID == df2$rsID, "x")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two dataframes and select non-NA value from `rsID` columns.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c('chr', 'position')) %>%
  mutate(rsID = coalesce(rsID.y, rsID.x)) %>%
  select(names(df1))

#  rsID chr position
#1    x  12      321
#2 rs12  14      412
#3    x  15     3123
#4 rs20  17      413
```

In base R :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = c('chr', 'position'), all.x = TRUE), 
          rsID = ifelse(is.na(rsID.y), rsID.x, rsID.y))[names(df1)]
```

Comment: I do not know whether your idea works well because there are two conditions: "only if corresponding values in two columns 'chr' and 'position' of df1 and df2 are the same". To my understanding, your code just matches corresponding values in the 'chr' column. Anw, I will give it a go